# Units for LLA to ECEF conversion

Tags: coordinate-system, coordinates, latitude-longitude, ecef

I wish to implement this formula from [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geographic_coordinate_conversion#From_geodetic_to_ECEF_coordinates) to convert LLA to ECEF 
coordinates:

[image: LLAtoECEF]

where

[image]

and a and b are the semi-major and semi-minor axes respectively.

My question is: what units will this work with? [This paper](https://microem.ru/files/2012/08/GPS.G1-X-00006.pdf) says the equation is in meters. I am wondering if it can be more general than that. Can I use any unit of distance so long as I am consistent?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- Semi-major (ie a), Semi-minor (ie b), and Ellipsoid Height (ie h) must be in the same unit of length, eg all must be in meters, or all in feets, and etc.
- Unit of measurement of X, Y, Z follow the unit of length of a, b, h.
- By convention, ECEF X, Y, Z are always in meters.

Answer (score 2):

As long as you use the same linear unit, you can use whatever linear unit you want. As far as I know, the angular units must be in radians.